# How to get a class property by its name using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have a few class like following :

```
 public class FileLineDeviceDto : FileLineDto
    {
       public string Name { get; set;      
       public string Group{ get; set; }
 
    }

 public class FileLineUserDto : FileLineDto
    {
       public string Firstname{ get; set;      
       public string Lastname{ get; set; }
       public string Address{ get; set; }
 
    }
```

I need to dosome treatments in excel files using those DTOs, like in the current case : do some uppercase.
As this treatment will be done many times on many classes; I'd like it to be reusable so I would like to retrieve the Properties of the class.

Let's say I need to uppercase the Lastnameof a FileLineUserDto. I'd like to retrieve that property by passing it's name.

So far, I tried something this :

```
private static void SetExcelColumnValuesToUpperCase<T>(ExcelFileDto file, string sheetName, string propertyName) where T : FileLineDto
{
    var prop = GetPropertyValue(typeof(T), propertyName);

    List<T> lines = sheet.Lines.OfType<T>().ToList();
    
    var valuesToUpdate = lines.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).Name?.Equals(prop.GetType().Name)).ToList();
    valuesToUpdate.ForEach(x => x.ToString()?.ToUpperInvariant());
}

private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyValue(object source, string propertyName)
{
    var property = source.GetType().GetProperties()
        .FirstOrDefault(p => string.Equals(p.Name, propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    return property;
}
```

The method is used like this :

```
SetExcelColumnValuesToUpperCase<FileLineEquipementDto>(classeurValide, Constants.Device.PAGE_NAME, "Name");
```

But if I check what I get as properties doing :

```
source.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

What I get is :

```
[0] "IsCollectible" string
[1] "DeclaringMethod"   string
[2] "FullName"  string
[3] "AssemblyQualifiedName" string
[4] "Namespace" string
[5] "GUID"  string
[6] "GenericParameterAttributes"    string
[7] "IsSZArray" string
```

And not Firstname, Lastname and Address...
Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `var prop = GetPropertyValue(typeof(T), propertyName);` Your passing a type then calling `GetType()` on it. Therefor  you enumerate the properties of the `Type` class, not T.  Consider changing the argument to `Type sourceType` and omitting the call to `GetType()` on it.

Comment: Might also want to look at the line `var valuesToUpdate...` - prop can be null as it's the result of `FirstOrDefault` but the line assumes it will always be non-null.  I'm also not sure what the generic is doing here, it's only used to get it's type. Did you mean to write `SetExcelColumnValuesToUpperCase<T>(T file`  -->  `GetPropertyValue(typeof(file), propertyName);` ?

Comment: @asawyer I tried `GetPropertyValue(T, propertyName)` but got 'T parameter is not valid at this point'... Any clue? As for the null exception, I do some checking before, just removed them so my question is more clear, but thank you :)

Comment: I updated the original post so it shows how SetExcelColumnValuesToUpperCase is called :)

Comment: T is not a type it's a generic argument. You could change the signature of `GetPropertyValue` to `GetPropertyValue<T>(string propertyName)` and forward it along, then call `typeof(T)` there. Then the call site would then be `var prop = GetPropertyValue<T>(propertyName);`

Comment: @asawyer Oh, well... Works like a charm ! thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Your welcome. Write up your solution as an answer and accept it.